# API file in NextJS is not executed at all

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js, websocket, endpoint

I am trying to build a simple website using sockets. The problem is not with the sockets though. I have an endpoint inside of my /pages/api directory called game.js, which contains the following code:

```
    const WebSocket = require('ws');

console.log('I AM EXECUTING');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });

wss.on('listening', () => {
    console.log('listening');
});

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log('Client connected');

    ws.on('message', (message) => {
        console.log(`Received message: ${message}`);
        wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
            if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                client.send(message);
            }
        });
    });

    ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
    });
});

export default function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.headers.upgrade !== 'websocket') {
        res.status(400).send('Expected WebSocket request');
        return;
    }

    const key = req.headers['sec-websocket-key'];
    wss.handleUpgrade(req, req.socket, key, onUpgrade);

    function onUpgrade(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('WebSocket upgrade failed:', error.message);
            res.end();
            return;
        }
        wss.emit('connection', req.socket);
    }
}
```

However, this code is never executed when I run 'npm run dev'. Even the console log which prints 'I AM EXECUTING' is never printed to the console. What could be the problem causing this? I have no errors in console, the application is launched, but I don't get 'I AM EXECUTED' message printed.